How to create connections and forks in streets
Hope you are all well. Newbie here.
I'm trying to create a little "neighborhood" and for better organization I started with the streets. For context, I researched several tutorials on the subject, all of which I found use the same technique (applying curves to planes) which is best summarized in the following video:
"How to Create a Road in Blender: A Step-by-Step Guide || Deepak Graphics" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9qZl00RqfA
My problem is that all these tutorials explain how to create linear roads, without forks. When I try to use the extrusion method on some vertex, instead of creating a new route, I end up having the original object distorted. Example:

I would like to create some forks, dead ends, like in the following image:

What would be the best approach? Should I create one object for the main route and others for the smaller ones? I'm also trying to keep the triangle count low, I'd even like the curves to be less smooth, more "abrupt" like in a low poly Ps1 game.
I found a similar question (maybe) on another platform, but I couldn't replicate the comment from user "Okidoki": https://blenderartists.org/t/how-can-be-create-street-model-and-render-streets-from-blender-gis/1506916/2

As far as with curves, there is no way to do it that I know of. The array modifier will just pick a single curve to use, and any other curves you generate within the curve will be ignored.
But you can use geometry nodes to achieve your intersections and junctions.
There are many tutorials on how to do this, but this is the one I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvQWA9SJEiY
Essentially, you create the mesh road network you want using vertices and edges.

Then you apply this geometry node group to generate the roads.

It's worth noting this will not work as well in cycles as it does in EEVEE.

Sorry, I'm new here and I didn't see anything about linking answers being prohibited in the site tour.

@AlexEdwards no problem. Thank you very much for updating it into a good and nice answer! +1 for that :)
